# 8086 Assembly - Better data storage/manipulation?

Tags: loops, assembly

I am working on a project for class, and it works as required by the rubric, though I am wondering if there is a slightly better way to implement a few things. I was docked a few points for an unnecessary 'mov' in another project. Here is problem 1.

"If—else (34 points): Write a program that asks the user to enter a single digit. If that digit is less 5, you will state so and you will add 5 to it and store it in a variable; if the digit is greater than 5, you will state so and then subtract 5 from it and store it in a variable; if the digit is 5, you will add 3 to it and state so and store it in a variable."

```
org 100h   
mov dx, offset start   ;move start of string address 'start' into dx
mov ah, 09h   
int 21h                ;print the string stored at DS:DX
mov ah, 01h            ;function for getting keyboard input
int 21h
sub al, 30h            ;subtract 30h to store our number as hexadecimal
mov bl, al             ;copying data to BL as the following commands manipulate the data
                       ;at AL. 
cmp bl, 5              ;BL = AL
jz ifZero              ;jump to ifZero if BL = 5
jl ifLess              ;jump to isLess if BL < 5
jg ifGreater           ;jump to ifGreater if BL > 5

ifZero:                ;direct console output function
mov ah, 06h            
mov dl, 0Ah
int 21h
mov dl, 0Dh
int 21h                ;print newline and character return
add bl, 03h            ;add 3 to BL, BL = 8
mov temp, bl           
mov dx, offset eq      ;move start of string address 'eq' into dx
mov ah, 09h
int 21h                ;print string
jmp exit               ;unconditional jump to end program

ifLess:                ;direct console output function
mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0aH
int 21h
mov dl, 0Dh
int 21h                ;print newline and character return
add bl, 05h            ;add 5 to BL
mov temp, bl           
mov dx, offset less    ;move start of string address 'less' into dx
mov ah, 09h
int 21h                ;print string
jmp exit               ;unconditional jump to end program

ifGreater: 
mov ah, 06h            
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h                ;print newline and character return
sub bl, 05h            ;subtract 5 from BL
mov temp, bl
mov dx, offset great   ;move starting address of string 'great' into dx
mov ah, 09h
int 21h                ;print string
jmp exit               ;unconditional jump to end program


exit:
ret

temp db ? 
start db "Please enter a number: $"
less db "Less than 5... adding 5 $"
great db "Greater than 5... subtracting 5 $"
eq db "Equal to 5... adding 3 $"
```

in this case, would 'mov bl, al' be not needed? Running through the disassembler shows that the data in AL changes after most of these commands. Is this supposed to happen? Is there a better way to do so?

Problem 3:
Counter-controlled loop. The program will ask the user to enter a character and then it will display
that character with a label five times
For example:
Enter a character: A
You entered: A

```
org 100h
mov cx, 05h             ;counter controlled loop, start as 5

LabelLoop:
mov dx, offset prompt   ;move string offset to dx
mov ah, 09h             ;function for printing string from dx
int 21h
mov ah, 01h             ;function to read character from keyboard
int 21h    
mov bl, al              ;preserving character read by copying to BL
                        ;as register data for AL will be changing
                        ;due to various functions
mov ah, 06h             ;function for direct console output
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h
mov dl, 0dh             ;these just make the text appear on a new
                    ;line
int 21h
mov dx, offset output   ;move the memory offset of output to dx
mov ah, 09h             ;printing another string
int 21h
mov ah, 02h             ;function to write a character to console
                        ;gets the value from DL
mov dl, bl                  ;so we copy BL to DL and print it
int 21h
jmp newLine             ;we unconditionally jump to the newLine
                        ;label and print a new line for the program
                        ;to run again

newLine:
mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h
mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
loop LabelLoop         ;we jump to LabelLoop and CX = CX - 1

mov dx, offset goodbye
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

ret

prompt db 'Enter a character: $'
output db 'You entered: $'
goodbye db 'Good bye!$'
```

So, my question for these problems, is there a better way to do this? keyboard input is stored in AL, but the register value changes for each time i do a mov function into AH, whether string printing or character printing. in order to avoid a variable (since it wasn't a part of the requirements) or allocating it to memory (which we haven't learned), I moved the data to a different register. Is this an unnecessary 'mov' for either program?

edit: i realize that AL = DL after

```
mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h       ;AL = DL after execution
```

Comment: Please post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and you will get better answers, since that site is exclusively for this kind of questions and on SO they are off topic as working program enhancements.

Comment: Indent your instructions one level to the right from your labels, so it's easy to see the branch labels.  I like to indent operands to the same tab stop, instead of having a ragged column of operands due to variable-length insn mnemonics.  (I also like to indent jump targets slightly less than other operands, so branches stand out as well as branch targets).  The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a link on formatting asm nicely.  You're doing well with comment formatting, and ok with content, BTW.  Generally avoid describing what an insn does, just say what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> cmp bl, 5              ;BL = AL
> jz ifZero              ;jump to ifZero if BL = 5
> jl ifLess              ;jump to isLess if BL < 5
> jg ifGreater           ;jump to ifGreater if BL > 5
> ifZero:
> ```

The first improvement you should do is making use of the possibility to fall-through in the code. Don't use `jz ifZero` but rather fall through as equality is the only state that remains after `jl` and `jg`. Also **ifEqual** would be a more correct name for this state.

```
cmp bl, 5              ;BL = AL
jl ifLess              ;jump to isLess if BL < 5
jg ifGreater           ;jump to ifGreater if BL > 5
ifEqual:
```

A second optimization will be to get rid of all of those direct console outputs for CR and LF. You should incorporate these in the messages that you will print. Doing so will also remove the need to copy AL to BL using `mov bl, al` (you specifically asked this):

```
less  db 13,10,"Less than 5... adding 5 $"
great db 13,10,"Greater than 5... subtracting 5 $"
eq    db 13,10,"Equal to 5... adding 3 $"
```

Here's another opportunity to fall through:

```
jmp exit               ;unconditional jump to end program
exit:
```

Your second program can benefit from these advices too.